# Shopify StoreFront API GraphQL query returns nothing

Tags: graphql, shopify, gatsby, storefront, graphiql

I am trying for a client to build his Shopify store with Gatsby. I use for that [gatsby-source-shopify2](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-shopify2/) plugin, and I always had error messages like that :

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"allShopifyProduct\" on type \"Query\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So I investigated a bit to know what was happening, and I went on Shopify help center, followed [this quick tuto](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/custom-storefronts/storefront-api/getting-started#accessing-the-storefront-api-graphql-endpoint) and reproduced it with my client's store and with my own freshly created free test-store.
Here are the step I followed :

1. Create a new store, called 'my-store'
2. Create a new product
3. Create a new private app
4. Check the box `Allow this app to access your storefront data using the Storefront API`
5. Copy the API key
6. Double-check that the private app is checked in the `Product Availability`, just to be sure
7. Open GraphiQL, and set the GraphQL Endpoint to be `https://my-store.myshopify.com/api/graphql`
8. Set the only HTTP Header to be: `X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token`: `<API key>`

Then I typed in the query field :

```
{
  shop {
    name
  }
}
```

And surprisingly, no error happened, but the expected output didn't come. It should have been :

```
{
  "data": {
    "shop": {
      "name": "my-store",
    }
  }
}
```

I tried in gatsby too, and the same errors came again, obviously.

What is wrong with me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, my mistake, I went to fast : in the private app you have many keys : `<API key>`, `<shared secret>` and `<API Storefront access token>`. I used the `<API key>` instead of the `<API Storefront access token>`. Now everything is OK...